# Generate permutations

Tags: excel, vba, permutation

I have n players to assign to n games. `10 <= n <= 20`. Each player can sign up for up to 3 games but will only get one. Different players have different score for each game they sign up for.

Example with 10 players:

[image: score of 10 players]

It's always possible to assign players x to game x but it will not always give the highest score in total.

My goal is to get as high score as possible and I therefore want to test the different permutations. I could teoretically test all permutations and throw away the unfeasible ones but it will give me a hughe number of possibilities (`n!`). 
Is it possible to reduce the problem with the sign up limit of max 3 games? Maybe this can be done more easily than my approach? Any thoughts?
I'm working in Excel VBA.

I hope you find this as interesting as I do ...

Sorry if you find this unclear! My question is if it's possible to generate a subset of all the permutations. More precise only the feasible ones (which are the ones without any zero score).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. In order to get good answers, you may want to edit your question. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand why you try to find all the permutations to find the highest score. Isn't the highest score just the maximum of the shown table? If not, please explain what do you mean by *"It's always possible to assign players x to game x but it will not always give the highest score in total."*?

Comment: It's possible that extending on the possibilities of the rank() function may be of use to you. Have a look at http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/rank.aspx - should that not help you please rephrase your question.

Comment: A player will ony be assigned 1 game. If player sign up for 3 games player will have 3 potential scores but only the score of the game player is assigned will count.

Comment: @ExternalUse, the rank function seems interesting, I will study it more to see if it can help me

Comment: There are several posts about permutations in here already with answers, have a search...

Comment: I found a workaround for the moment. I can generate small subsets of permutations, 5 at a time, and after that I combine them to a solution. It will not investigate all possibilities but a large number and it gives me a better solution than the strategies I used so far.

Comment: @SolarMike, yes I have searched a lot before posting. I found great help with permutations but not a problem similar to mine.

Comment: You should be able to set this up and use the solver.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just set this up in the solver using Linear Programming as you can see in the image. Have shown the formulae so you can build it as well, along with the solver settings.

Won't give the permutations, but does solve for the highest combination.
Edit, updated image... it now shows correct ranges for the calculations, after trying to make it fit a reasonable size...

[image]

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes, that's what happened, but updated now thanks.